# Access View Controller method from App Delegate in Swift - asking for parameter

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am trying to call a method from my view controller in the app delegate file, and it is asking for a parameter of the type of whatever class I am trying to call. ie: what is happening is that I am trying to call a method from the messages_send_message.swift class / file, and for any method in that file (including the ones without parameters) it wants a parameter of `messages_send_message`.

what is happening: I am trying to call the `update` method from the app delegate file when it receives a push notification. So that if they are already in the chat, it just updates/refreshes the feed.

so here is the method: `messages_send_message.update()`
and it is asking for: `messages_send_message.update(messages_send_message)`

But it throws an error by that parameter when I try to use it. I also tried putting the `()` after the `messages_send_message` parameter, but same issue, still get the errors.

Anyone know a fix?

By the way, the error is: `Missing argument for parameter #q in call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `update` doesn't reference self, then make it a class method and that will fix your problem.

If the method does reference self, then you need an instance of the class to call the method.